# How to manage the Azure APIM developer portal delegation with Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

I want to enable the Azure APIM developer portal sign-in & sign-up delegation and to generate a "Delegation Validation Key". This is straightforward with the Azure portal:
[image]

I want to achieve the same thing but with Azure PowerShell as part of a bigger deployment pipeline.
I cannot find any documentation on how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @StakAtak ,Kindly verify the answer if it has rectified your issue. This verification would help the other community members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, We can not achieve the above requirement using powershell , Here are  the details ([**`MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/powershell-samples)) for what we can configure through powershell for APIM .

[image]

Instead of that we can configure the above requirement using git , Please refer this [**`MICRSOFT DOCUMENTATION`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git) for more details & the list of [***`cmdlets`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/?view=azps-7.4.0) for APIM .

Answer (score 0):

An additional option is to use an HTTP call against the resource. The call can be made with the PowerShell script as well.
This can be done as follows:

1. Get an Azure access token - you should have a Service Principal with sufficient permissions for the resource we are going to deal with.

   $tokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token"
   $form = @{
   grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
   resource      = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
   client_id     = $spClientId
   client_secret = $spClientSecret
   }
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenUri -Method Post -Body $form
   $azureToken = $response.access_token
2. Send an HTTP request against the APIM service

   ```
    $url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${apiManagementRg}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/${apiManagementName}/portalsettings/delegation?api-version=2020-12-01"
   ```

   $headers = @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer ${azureToken}" }

   $body = @"
   {
   "properties": {
   "url": "$delegationUrl",
   "validationKey": "$validationKey",
   "subscriptions": {
   "enabled": false
   },
   "userRegistration": {
   "enabled": true
   }
   }
   }
   "@

   $delegationResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Put' -Body $body -Uri $url -Headers $headers